# Differences between Array Collection syntax

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, adobe

Hi All,
I was wondering what's the difference between doing

`public var arrayVar:ArrayCollection`
type 1
`arrayVar = new ArrayCollection(event.result as Array)`
type 2
`arrayVar = event.result as ArrayCollection`
However type 2 seems to work, but more people seem to reference type 1

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I code in VB, and i sorta understand c# for the most part, so take my post with a grain of salt =)
but it would appear as if "Type 1" is creating a new array and filling it with the data in theevent.results object and "Type 2" is casting the event.result object into the variable "arrayVar"

If I'm right, then in simple terms...
In "Type 1" you are creating a new ArrayCollection using an existing array object, which you plan on reading/writing to while preserving the original event.results object

Whereas, in "Type 2" you are casting event.results into variable "arrayVar" which if you modify, you'll be modifying the original event.results object as well.

I could be wrong, but that's my interpretation =)